# How can I change an html element from ruby using sinatra and bootstrap

Tags: html, ruby, sinatra

Here is my index.erb file:

```
  <a class="btn" href='javascript:TestFunction()' role="button">TestFunction</a>

  <script language="javascript"> 

     function TestFunction() {
       $.post("test_function", { action: "foo", name: "bar" } );
     }

  </script>
</body>
```

And my app.rb file looks like this

```
class ConfigureApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    erb :index
  end

  post '/test_function' do
    button_action = params.fetch("action")
    test_class = TestClass.new
    test_class.action(button_action)
  end
end
```

TestClass.rb file:

```
class TestClass
  def action(button_action)
    if button_action == "foo"
      new_button_label = "something else"
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a way for me to change the TestFunction button's label from TestClass? So using the examples I have above, could i rename the TestFunction button, "something else"?

Comment: You'll need to do something with jQuery or javascript on the client side, I think so that the button label is reset dynamically based on the return of an AJAX call?  (TL;DR: this smells like a jQuery question to me....)

Comment: Do you want to change it dynamically while the user is browsing the page or do you want different calls to result in different labels? In the first case you need javascript just as Andy said but in the second case it is possible to do it from ruby. You'll need to pass in params to the `erb` in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it. I could send post '/test_function' and send the action and name parameters. Then use a function as the 3rd parameter of the post function to get a return from the Ruby side, which could return the button's new label. I could then use Jquery to update the button's html or innerText or whatever I need to update. This is how I implemented this:

```html
  <a class="btn" id='btn-foo' href='javascript:TestFunction()' role="button">TestFunction</a>

  <script language="javascript"> 

     function TestFunction() {
       $.post("test_function", { action: "foo", name: "bar" }, function(data) {
         $('#btn-foo').html = data;
       });
     }

  </script>
</body>
```